# .net core 3.0 grpc error statucode=canceled

Tags: grpc, asp.net-core-3.0

I got an error when using grpc in .net core 3.0,

Here is error message:

```
[Grpc.Core.RpcException:“Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="No grpc-status found on response.")”]
```

My grpc server is like this :

one .net core Library with package grpc.aspnetcore(2.25) and one .net core api project  with package grpc.aspnetcore.server(2.25), I register service in startup file. When I call the service in grpc client

I got the error As mentioned above.

This project directory structure
this is service register
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By0hS.png)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a  grpc.aspnetcore.server(2.25) , startup file?  do you call 
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
});

Comment: That's what I did

Comment: Are you shure that server is started and work? Can you check that port 44320 is bussy? Can you check that firewall is not block your requests?

Comment: Yes, the request can arrive at the server and be executed. When the client receives the return value, an error is reported

Comment: What's your  `NHBPddServiceIpm` and `greet.proto` file  ? How do you implement the  service that `NHBPddServiceIpm` inherited? Could you provide a complete simple project , as your Grpc service does not use the default template and it contains some customized objects?

Comment: when i using default template  it works well.
I want grpc to work with the API

Answer (score 3):

I found when run service as IIS-Express, The client always error.  But run it as ProjectName, The client work fine! 
[run ways image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G4g6.jpg)

I do not know why, but that just happened. So you can try it.

Comment: You are correct. apparently grpc isn't support in IIS. you configured VS to run under kestrel (default) instead of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS/IIS express. I was hitting the same issue when i lauched it in IISExpress. Change your launchSetting.json values as below and it will work.

`{
  "profiles": {
    "Greeter": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {

        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: So what is the actual fix? Which of these is the problem? What are we fixing here? what are we doing?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when running the API under IIS. This is the default, and if you are running multiple startup projects, it is likely running under IIS.

To fix:

- Check what HTTPS address/port your API project is running under (https://localhost:5001 is the default)
- Target just the API project and change the run type from II Express to console (select whatever your project name is. See
  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNOGF.png))
- Change the startup projects to target your API and client app and run.

You should have two black console windows, and hopefully your call will be successful!

Answer (score 0):

Kerwin Zhang solution is correct.

Check your Asp.Net core logs or the vs output window when you return from the service, you'll see some grpc trailer not supported exceptions. it most likely means you run the server with IIS or some unsupported platform... [gRPC in ASP.NET Core currently doesn't support HttpSys/IIS/IIS Express](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/665).

Start the same project as **[kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1)** instead of IIS and it should now work fine.
(In VS Start debug button drop down change from [IIS Express] To [Your Project])